# Admin rights per project

Tags: tfs

Lets say I want to handle a project in Team Foundation. Is there diffrent admin rights for that?

What I mean is if you are ADMIN on the hole Team Foundation Server then you can create a project. But then you will have access to ALL projects that is created.

Is there a way to handle admin rights that some admin can only use this project2 and some only use this project2.

I hope I make myself clear what I am after. :-)

Comment: Your last sentence should be "some admin can only use this project and some only use this project2." right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS 2010 introduced the concept of team project collections which can be adminsered on separate security level than team projects.

Refer to MSDN Magazine article: [Visual Studio TFS Team Project and Collection Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983486.aspx)

[image: Visual Studio TFS Team Project and Collection Guidance]